# Microsoft Example 52 and AAD ConnectionName from the OAuth Connection Settings on Azure

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to get started with microsoft example https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config. I don't have an azure account so I use in "To try this sample -> 4." the registration without azure account. In the next step (5.) i should update appsettings.json. Now I was wondering what to include in code for  AAD ConnectionName from OAuth Connection settings on azure.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely need an Azure account for this, but you can look at the free Microsoft 365 Developer program for this. I think it even gives a dummy Office 365 tenancy - see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program

Comment: sure, glad to help